Exception on PCANBasic.Read
I am using the python PCAN Basic api and when I connect to my CAN network, I keep getting a message that says Exception on PCANBasic.Read. The code that is catching this exception is:
        try:
            msg = TPCANMsg()
            timestamp = TPCANTimestamp()
            res = self.__m_dllBasic.CAN_Read(Channel,byref(msg),byref(timestamp))
            return TPCANStatus(res),msg,timestamp
        except:
            print ("Exception on PCANBasic.Read")
            raise    

Output:
Exception on PCANBasic.Read

I did some investigation and found that the exception is a System Exit exception with a code of None. This is what I did to catch that:
        try:
            msg = TPCANMsg()
            timestamp = TPCANTimestamp()
            res = self.__m_dllBasic.CAN_Read(Channel,byref(msg),byref(timestamp))
            return TPCANStatus(res),msg,timestamp
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard interupt")
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("Generator interupt")
        except SystemExit as e:
            print(f"System Exit Exception on PCANBasic.Read with code: {e.code}")
        except Exception as e:
            print (f"Exception on PCANBasic.Read: {e}")
            raise

Output:
System Exit Exception on PCANBasic.Read with code: None

This appears regularly, only when there is activity on the network.
What could be causing this?
